# Formatting warning for stacktraces

Tags: feature-request, new-users, formatting

Many new users seem to have a hard time finding the proper formatting for stacktraces. They format them either not at all or a quotes. Both makes them hard to read. Since Stacktraces are rather structured I wonder if it would be possible to either have a warning if a user tries to save a question which seems to contain a stacktrace not formatted as source code or alternatively having a bot suggesting edits for such questions.

After playing with some formatting to see what is actually happening:

It would be cool if this would apply to any kind of strongly formatted text, so it would include for example logs.

Comment: How do you format stacktraces? I'm assuming you think they should be formatted with the _code tool_.  I've seen them in quotes and they look fine to me.

Comment: @George Sometimes they come out alright when formatted as quotes, but most of the time the additional linebreaks make it hard to do a quick scan of the package names to find the interesting parts...

Comment: Yes, I think they should get formatted as code. Quotes don't seem to get vertical scrollbars and wrap longer lines which makes it much harder to parse.

Comment: @George formatting in a quote block is fine when the fully qualified class names are short enough (short enough to fit into one line). If they are too long, then only code formatting looks reasonable.